# I'm having difficulty using a swift function from another file, I constantly get the error "expression resolves to an unused function"

Tags: swift

Here is the function I try to call from a different file...

```
func setLoginStatusT() -> (){
    status = true
    println("Logged In")
    ProgramStart()
}
```

and here is how I am trying to call it...

```
    Main.setLoginStatusT
```

What does "expression resolves to an unused function" even mean?

Answer (score 1):

This `setLoginStatusT() -> ()` means that you are returning a function. If you don't want to return anything try this

```
func setLoginStatusT(){ //-> (){
    status = true
    println("Logged In")
    ProgramStart()
}
```

`“expression resolves to an unused function”` this means that you should do something with the returning value of the method, like assign it to a variable, in this case you can just run the method you are getting, try this:

```
Main.setLoginStatusT()
```

Comment: ok now i get a different error "missing argument for parameter #1 to call"

Comment: its highlighting->  Main.setLoginStatusT()

Comment: If you change the method, you don't need to use the parenthesis. just use Main.setLoginStatusT

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to call the `setLoginStatusT` method which is within the `Main` class, but you are making the call from inside a different class. Here's how to write that call:

```
Main().setLoginStatusT()
```

You would not need the `()` after `Main` if the `setLoginStatusT` method were a class level method. But in this example, I am assuming that `setLoginStatusT` is an instance level method of the `Main` class, so you need the `()`.